# Magento 2: Disable checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout

I'm slowly setting up my shop. All products are available to view and shop is enabled for external visitors, for SEO purposes. However I don't want to sell anything right now.

What is the easiest way to switch off Magento checkout page - how to disable making orders?

Comment: You should also enable demo notice on website, so customer will get information. If you only disable shipping/payment, customer will get a negative impression...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable Payments and Shipping methods to stop the checkout process on the website.

You can follow the below paths for the same.

**For disabling Shipping**: `Magento Admin > Stores > Sales > Shipping Methods` and disable all the active shipping methods.

**For disabling Payment**: `Magento Admin > Stores > Sales > Payment Methods` and disable all the active payment methods.

Also, you can set a redirect to the Home page or any custom page you want for the checkout page URL. You can setup the URL rewrite by following the below path in the Magento Admin.

```
Marketing > SEO & Search > URL Rewrites.
```

Hope it helps!